# VXX Put pricing

Tags: options, volatility, implied-volatility, pricing, vix

Last week at Friday's close, the Dec 14 37.5 Put options were selling for \$.68 with VXX at \$40.29. This week at Friday's close, the Dec 21 37.5 Put options were selling for \$.38 with VXX at \$40.50. Almost the same exact amount of time to expiration and VXX was at almost the exact same price, yet the puts are selling for over 40% less! Why is this so?

Comment: Name your top three considerations for why this might be and someone will help you work through it.

Answer (score 1):

Last week (9-14) there were FOMC/ECB/BOJ decisions, this week (17-21) it's almost Christmas and traders care more about getting dinner reservations and buying turkeys than options, it makes sense to pay a bit less for very short term implied volatility of volatility than last week.

Let's simplify (a lot) and assume that the VIX is 2 months volatility spot (it's actually a weighted average of 2 futures so it's a forward vol + your ETN has time decay). Anyway, let's label it `2M VOL(SP500)`. Your 1 week VXX option is dependent on the implied volatility of volatility. Let's label it `1W VOL(2M VOL(SP500))`

The fact that your `2M VOL(SP500)` (much longer term compared to your 1 week option) is unchanged doesn't mean that `1W VOL(2M VOL(SP500))` is unchanged. Traders assume that the `2M VOL(SP500)` is going to be less volatile (which doesn't mean lower) this week than what they expected the previous week.